# strcat Skipping letters or Adding letters

Tags: c, string, strcat

I am currently trying to create an application that parses a file and changes some strings around, but that's not what's important.

I am currently trying to combine a few strings in order to produce a unified result; however, the results do not seem to be consistent with the code. Here is the code:

```
/* Now let's recombine the strings */
strcat(slash+1, secondSlash+1);
printf("\nFirst  String: %s", toConvert);
printf("\nSecond String: %s", slash+1);
strcat(toConvert, slash+1);
printf("\nFinal  String: %s", toConvert);
```

The output looks a little something like this:

```
First  String: **1)** 
Second String: *rails new <websiteName> *
Final  String: **1)** *rails nw <webssiteName> *
```

Why is the final string not an accurate concatenation of the two original Strings? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How are the variables `slash`, `secondSlash`, and `toConvert` defined? How are memory allocated for them?

Comment: `char toConvert[BUFSIZE];`  

`char *slash = strchr(toConvert, '/');`  
  
`char *secondSlash = strchr(slash+2, '/')`

Keep in mind that toConvert is eventually filled with stuff and that slash and secondSlash are both null-terminated.

Comment: Works perfectly on local machine. BTW why slash+1?

Comment: slash+1 because I wanted to hide the first character while displaying the string. It is interesting because sometimes the output is as expected, sometimes it is not. Do you think it has something to do with BUFSIZ's limitation? I don't think that would explain the additional characters, though.

Comment: I don't see any no checks to avoid undefined behavior when `slash` and `secondSlash` are `NULL`.

Comment: If `slash` and `secondSlash` pointers are in the *same* buffer you likely have an overlapped concatenation with your first `strcat`. **C99 7.23.3.1p2**: "...If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined." You may wanna look into that.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks so much! I was unaware of this. They were definitely on the same buffer (Which upon further inspection, is definitely a bad idea), and now I am using another method for solving this. Thanks!

Comment: @brandonio21 I suspected it was such given the names (pretty thin guess, actually, but it made sense in my head, anyway. Glad it helped.

Comment: Another problem is that you don't check the result of `strchr` is not `NULL` before using that result as an argument to `printf` or `strcat`. In future post your actual code, including the contents which cause the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @WhozCraig, the problem with this was a violation of the following:

```
C99 7.23.3.1p2: "...If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined."
```

Thus, in order to solve the problem, I stopped using the `strcat` function and instead manually shifted all of the elements of my strings to the left. (Previously I was using a strategy where I set the concatenation points to `'\0'` and `strcat` them together. This was obviously not optimal.

In order to fix this, I just looped through the entire char array and moved all elements left. Here is a snippet of my code for reference:

```
/* Move all things to the left */
int index;
for (index = (slash+2-toConvert); index <= secondSlash-toConvert; index++)
    toConvert[index-1] = toConvert[index];

/* Now move all things after the secondSlash area left */
int secondIndex = secondSlash+2-toConvert;
while(toConvert[secondIndex] != '\0')
{
    toConvert[secondIndex-2] = toConvert[secondIndex];
    secondIndex++;
}
/* Add null char */
toConvert[secondIndex-2] = '\0';
```

Hopefully this helps someone.